# Promise should not be async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Why should a Promise not be async? And how do I have to change this function?
With this I'm handling some files using gridFS and it is working as expected. But now I got the linting error not to use async promises. If I remove `async`, the function is not working anymore.

```
export async function getFiles () {
  await db.connect()
  const Images = db.gfs

  return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) { // <-- linting error
    Images
      .find()
      .toArray((err, files) => {
        if (err) reject(Error(err))
        else if (!files) reject(Error('Failed to retrieve pending files'))
        if (anyCondition) { resolve(something) }
        else { resolve(files.filter(file => !file.metadata)) }
      })
  })
}
```

Comment: which async do you remove which makes the error occur?

Comment: You're wrapping a Promise (returned by the `async` function callback) in a Promise (via the constructor and the `new` keyword). I don't see a reason to use both, you should just have `new Promise(function() /*...*/`. It's also likely you don't need the wrapper promise, either but it's a bit hard to say.

Comment: `async`/`await` is syntactic sugar around `Promise` so you *don't have to explicitly create promises and use callbacks.* Using both together defeats the purpose.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm doing this because I have some condition inside the `toArray()` which resolves in different results. As I said, just removing the `async` is not working-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work with some function modularization:

```
async function otherGetFiles(){
   await db.connect();
   return await getFiles (db);
}

export function getFiles (db) {
  const Images = db.gfs
  return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
    Images
      .find()
      .toArray((err, files) => {
        if (err) reject(Error(err))
        else if (!files) reject(Error('Failed to retrieve pending files'))

        // do some things here...    
        resolve(files.filter(file => !file.metadata))
      })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. This would work without any errors or warnings.

```js
export async function getFiles() {
    await db.connect()
    const Images = db.gfs

    return await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Images
            .find()
            .toArray((err, files) => {
                if (err) reject(Error(err))
                else if (!files) reject(Error('Failed to retrieve pending files'))

                // do some things here...    
                resolve(files.filter(file => !file.metadata))
            })
    })
}
```

Comment: `return` does not need `await` as it is redundant